# insert into database with condition

Tags: php

When I update the `book_Status` from table `book` to `AVAILABLE` I do not succeed to change `reserve_Status`  to `RESERVED`. What's wrong with my script ?

**reserve.php**:

```
<?php
        include 'dbconnect.php';

        $query1 ="  
                    SELECT b.book_Status, r.reserve_Status

                    FROM book b
                    JOIN reservations r
                    ON r.book_Accession = b.book_Accession
                    ";


        $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die('SQL error');
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        if ($row1['book_Status'] == 'Available')
        {
            $Reserved = "Reserved";

        }               
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO reservations
                        WHERE reserve_Status = '$Reserved' ";

?>
```

Comment: Please explain more what are you trying to do! You can't insert with a `WHERE` clause. Inserts are just inserts why would they have a where.

Comment: Please post the full structure of the table you want to use

Comment: Hint: You should be doing an `UPDATE` query, not insert

Comment: You want to use `UPDATE reservations SET 'column' = 'value' WHERE reserve_status = 'reserved';`

Comment: I want to changed reserve_Status when the borrower update the book_Status to AVAILABLE.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `update query`. and move that query into your `if` statement

```
if ($row1['book_Status'] == 'Available')
        {
            $Reserved = "Reserved";
$query2 = "UPDATE reservations SET reserve_status = 'reserved' WHERE book_Status='Available'";

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the coding.. But reserve_Status and book_Status is a different table..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you changed the value of the variable `$Reserved` but you did not query the database to perform the update.